# JTA Transaction with multiple participants

Tags: jdbc, jms, jta, xa

I'm having trouble finding a simple example of a JTA transaction spanning multiple resources (e.g. two databases, a database and a JMS queue, etc.)

I've spent a lot of time reading up on this and have working samples of doing a JTA transaction with a JMS queue, and a JTA transaction over a JDBC database driver.  I just can't seem to find anything on making both the JMS queue and the JDBC database part of the same JTA transaction.

Can anyone provide a brief sample or a link to something that does demonstrate how to use the JTA API for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

For a JTA transaction to coordinate amongst JMS and JDBC resources, the following is required:

1. **XAConnectionFactory** - a JMS XA-compliant connection factory must be available in JNDI; the specific one to use depends on your application server/container.
2. **XA-compliant JDBC driver** - the driver must be XA, most databases provide one, and the connection must support `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, anything less won't be sufficient.

Aside from that, if you're using an app server, the container will handle transactions automatically if you're using message driven beans and XA-compliant drivers.

Check these links for exmaples:
http://blog.inflinx.com/2010/04/08/spring-jta-jpa-jms/
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-140431.html#relship_transac